# ADO.NET lock object

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, ado.net, locking

I have the following code...

```
    private DbTransaction Transaction;

    private readonly object TargetObject = new object();

    public CustomDataReader GetDataReader(CustomCommand command)
    {
        DbDataReader reader = null;        

        lock (TargetObject) // what is the purpose of this lock?
        {                                   
            DbCommand cmd = ProviderFactory.CreateCommand();
            cmdConnection = Connection;
            cmd.CommandText = command.Script;
            cmd.Transaction = Transaction;

            foreach (CommandParameter param in command.Parameters)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(Parse(param));
            }

            OpenConnection();

            if (Transaction == null)
            {              
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            }
            else
            {
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }  
        }

        return new CustomDataReader(reader);
    }
```

I am trying to understand what is the purpose of the `lock(TargetObject)` ? As we use a transaction when we execute the command, why will we use that lock mechanism?

Comment: It's to prevent multiple C# threads from executing the code simultaneously. Why? Ask whoever wrote the code.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: the dude has left the building.

Answer (score 1):

It means that in a multi-threaded environment that section of code inside the lock section can only be executed in one thread at a time. This is different than a transaction which means that all the changes to the database either fail or succeed together.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx):

> the lock keyword marks a statement block as a critical section by obtaining the mutual-exclusion lock for a given object, executing a statement, and then releasing the lock.

Comment: I am asking this because I want to make that method Asyncronous. However within lock I know I cannot run await. Long story short: If I remove the lock, and make the method async, will there be any issues?

Comment: Since it is using a shared Connection object and a shared Transaction object (which also might close that shared connection) then yes, there may be issues with the current code. You should make it more encapsulated where each instance can execute without other instances opening/closing connection or using the same transaction.